# wget behaves differently on cygwin and centos

Tags: centos, wget, cygwin

On **cygwin** this command works as expected and exits immediately:

```
wget --post-file oryxblock.2018-10-10_20_40-07_591.204.txt --output-document - --header "Content-Type: text/csv"  http://htm-psycho-402.zxz.su:8080/ingest

--2018-10-11 11:51:09--  http://htm-psycho-402.zxz.su:8080/ingest
Resolving htm-psycho-402.zxz.su (htm-psycho-402.zxz.su)... 192.168.147.9
Connecting to htm-psycho-402.zxz.su (htm-psycho-402.zxz.su)|192.168.147.9|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204
2018-10-11 11:51:09 (0.00 B/s) - written to stdout [0]
```

On **Centos** wget waits for 60 seconds before continuing with the same arguments:

```
--2018-10-11 08:38:58--  http://htm-psycho-402.zxz.su:8080/ingest
Resolving htm-psycho-402.zxz.su (htm-psycho-402.zxz.su)... 192.168.147.9
Connecting to htm-psycho-402.zxz.su (htm-psycho-402.zxz.su)|192.168.147.9|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204
Length: unspecified
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

    [        <=>                            ] 0           --.-K/s   in 60s

2018-10-11 08:39:58 (0.00 B/s) - written to stdout [0]
```

why does it happen?

Comment: does curl show the same latency ?

Comment: What are the versions of Wget on both systems? Maybe they're different versions? Also, it would be more helpful if you could share the output with the `--debug` flag on the centos system.

Comment: curl works quickly